# How to make sure your API key cannot just be copied and used

Tags: authentication, web-application, cryptography, privacy, api

One thing I often struggle with when developing my API's is authentication. I didn't have much trouble with this when I was making them for just a single website and was able to implement the following flow:

1. Server creates a session on request
2. A hidden input field called `accessToken` gets the value of this session
3. Upon a query to the API, it sends the hidden `accessToken` field
4. If they match, the request is authenticated

This method seemed pretty fool proof since with each new request to the site, a new accessToken was validated.

I have now moved onto developing apps that feed off the same API as my website and am having a harder time figuring out authentication. Now that I have an app, I can't simply just send the value of a session to the app like I could with my PHP based website. For simple get requests of public data, authentication wouldn't be required but when I create a user account, modify that users account, etc... I would want to make sure the request is coming from the proper source, not from someone who simply took the authentication key and is running the request in postman or curl.

Any ideas on how I could properly authenticate would be great, this is a concept that I've struggled with massively for a while and need to at least somewhat understand.

Comment: Couldn’t someone do the same thing in your original case? They make a request to your website, simply read the access token from the hidden field, and make any request they want with it? It’s the same with your app. Your app requests a token, reads it, and makes a request with that token. Both of these approaches seem bad as they’re both trusting the client, but maybe you could clarify the question if I’m not understanding it correctly.

Comment: @Steve no, they couldn't with the method I described since the session AND token must match. If they took the token provided and put it into postman, it would give them an error since there was no session on the server matching the token they were given.

Comment: The PHP session ID is just stored in a cookie, so it’s trivial to copy that too and make the request with that session ID cookie.